# Printing a word every X seconds

Tags: java

I just started learning how to use interfaces and I was trying to figure out how to print a particular word (in this case "Howdy") every 10 seconds. I used the `TimerTask` and `Timer` classes in order to schedule my task to run every 10 seconds, but am I doing it the right way?

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.util.*;


public class Howdy2 {

    class PrintHowdy extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
           System.out.println("Howdy!"); 
        }
     }

     public static void main(String[] args){
     Timer timer = new Timer();
     timer.schedule(new PrintHowdy(), 10000);

     }


}
```

Comment: Swing is for UIs.  You want a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: your code looks fine but instead of swing you need to use these libraries for timer and timer task: `java.util.Timer`, `java.util.TimerTask`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick, and doesn't require the use of a `Timer` or `TimerTask`:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {

            public void run()
            {
                while (true){
                    System.out.println("Hello World");
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000); // 1 second
                    } catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this,

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
   while(true) {
new PrintHowdy().run();
Thread.sleep(10000)
}

     }
```

Comment: Thank you that actually helped!It's running now!

Comment: @user2012891 You can set it as the correct answer by clicking the checkmark next to my answer. Thanks

Comment: @user2012891 You should also give credit to the OP of an answer, which would have been me because of my comment (which I just made into an answer).

Answer (score 0):

In these kind of solutions you should also consider the case to stop the flow for a given condition;

```
    public class TestExecution02 implements Runnable {

        public boolean doLoop = true;

        public void run() {
                //------
            while(doLoop) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000); // 10 second
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                // do your job until it is closed
            }

            System.out.println("Thread closed !");
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {

            TestExecution02 testExecution = new TestExecution02();
            Thread myThread = new Thread (testExecution);
            myThread.start();

            // do something.....
            testExecution.doLoop = false;

        }
    }
```

Comment: A similar answer has been given already, re-posting it adds no value. -1.